# Python - Applying title() function to values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I've done a few methods for python on my data frame. However I'm wondering why my function is not working correctly and why it does not seem to be applying correctly, here is my code followed by the corresponding screenshot:

```
def clean_belfast_data(df):
    df.dropna(subset=['Ward Name'], inplace=True)    
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    #Perhaps I can't use inplace for this.
    df['Ward Name'].str.title().inplace=True
return df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a function. Your operations are not stored, That's your problem.

```
 df['Ward Name']= df['Ward Name'].dropna()
```

Then

```
df['Ward Name'] = df['Ward Name'].str.title()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
df['Ward Name'].str.title().inplace=True
```

to

```
df['Ward Name'] = df['Ward Name'].str.title()
```

The line `df['Ward Name'].str.title().inplace=True` is invalid python/pandas. I'm not sure why it runs without error, but it's not doing what you mean to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have two thing need to change ,

> `df['Ward Name'].str.title().inplace=True` 
>   this is wrong .

also , do not forget to assign it back , and usually we do not using `inplace = True` to modify the original data directly

```
def clean_belfast_data(df1):
    df=df1.copy()
    df.dropna(subset=['Ward Name'], inplace=True)    
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    #Perhaps I can't use inplace for this.
    df['Ward Name']=df['Ward Name'].str.title()
    return df

CrimeData_1=clean_belfast_data(crimeDate)
```